# Parse Company Info

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing, finance

I was wondering if anyone knows how to successfully parse the company name "Alcoa Inc." shown in the URL below. It would be much easier to show a picture but I do not have enough reputation. Any help would be appreciated.

http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&ei=LdwVUYC7Fp_YlgPBiAE

This is what I have tried so far using jsoup to parse the div class:

```
 <div class="appbar-snippet-primary">
<span>Alcoa Inc.</span>
</div>



public Elements htmlParser(String url, String element, String elementType, String returnElement){


        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Document parse = Jsoup.parse(doc.html());

            if (returnElement == null){

                return parse.select(elementType + "." + element);

            }

            else {

                return parse.select(elementType + "." + element + " " + returnElement);

            }


        }  

public String htmlparseGoogleStocks(String url){

        String pr = "pr";
        String appbar_center = "appbar-snippet-primary";
        String val = "val";

        String span = "span";
        String div = "div";
        String td = "td";

        Elements price_data;
        Elements title_data;
        Elements more_data;

        price_data = htmlParser(url, pr, span, null);

        title_data = htmlParser(url, appbar_center, div, span);

        //more_data = htmlParser(url, val, td, null);

        //String stockprice = price_data.text().toString();
        String title = title_data.text().toString();

        //System.out.println(more_data.text());

        return title;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Did you try looking at the HTML source?

Comment: I have successfully parsed the company price but for some reason my code will not grab the div that holds the company name.

Comment: Which HTML parser are you using? Myself I prefer JSoup. And you should not be posting an image of the page but rather the pertinent parts of the page's source HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I'd analyze the page of interest's source HTML, and then just use JSoup to extract the information. For instance, using a very small JSoup program like so:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class GoogleFinance {

   public static final String PAGE = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:XONE";  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(PAGE).get();

      Elements title = doc.select("title");

      System.out.println(title.text());
   }
}
```

You get in return:

> ExOne Co: NASDAQ:XONE quotes & news - Google Finance

It doesn't get much easier than that.